# Error [MongoError]: file with id not opened for writing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, meteor

we are using meteor 2.2.4 version in our application while connecting with external mongodb getting following errors

```
ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
W20230314-16:25:20.031(5.5)? (STDERR)     process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
W20230314-16:25:20.031(5.5)? (STDERR)                                   ^
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR) Error [MongoError]: file with id 6410529725a5697684023bed not opened for writing
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.MongoError.create (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs\grid_store.js:979:33
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR)     at handleCallback (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1416:5
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR)     at handleCallback (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
W20230314-16:25:20.032(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:683:5
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at handleCallback (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:171:5)
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at setCursorNotified (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:515:3)
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:599:16
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at queryCallback (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:232:18)
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR) Emitted 'error' event on GridReadStream instance at:
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at GridReadStream._error (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\gridfs-stream\lib\readstream.js:231:8)
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\gridfs-stream\lib\readstream.js:109:26
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs\grid_store.js:236:22
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at error (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs\grid_store.js:1060:5)
W20230314-16:25:20.033(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs\grid_store.js:979:16
W20230314-16:25:20.037(5.5)? (STDERR)     at handleCallback (ProjectDockerize\.meteor\local\isopacks\cfs_gridfs\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
W20230314-16:25:20.038(5.5)? (STDERR)     [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
W20230314-16:25:20.038(5.5)? (STDERR)     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
W20230314-16:25:20.038(5.5)? (STDERR)   driver: true
W20230314-16:25:20.038(5.5)? (STDERR) }
```

Here is my meteor list
mongo 1.11.0* Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
cfs:access-point  0.1.49* CollectionFS, add ddp and http accesspoint capability
cfs:filesystem  0.1.2* Filesystem storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:gridfs 0.0.34+ GridFS storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:standard-packages  0.5.10* Filesystem for Meteor, collectionFS

Comment: I doubt that you get this error **while connecting to a MongoDB**

Comment: we are generating pdf in the meteor application. when we generating pdf couple of times like 4 to 5 times it works but after that getting the above issue for particular report. we are upgraded our application from meteor 1.9.2 to 2.2.4